# PagedList con mas de una clase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo tres tablas mapeadas con Entity Framework: maestros, clases e inscripciones. Necesito mostrar algunos campos de los maestros y algunos campos de las clases y mostrar el resultado en una vista usando un PagedList si lo pongo de la siguiente manera me sale este error:

Error CS1061 'GroupReport' no contiene una definición para 'ToPagedList' y ningún método de extensión 'ToPagedList'
aceptando un primer argumento de tipo 'GroupReport' podría encontrarse (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

```
using colegio.Datos;
using colegio.Models;
using PagedList;

public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            const int pageSize = 20;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            var clases = db.claseTs.Include(t => t.aulaT);

            var maestros = db.maestroTs.Include(t => t.alumnoT);

            var inscripciones = db.inscripcionTs.Include(t => t.membresiaT);

            var grupo = new GruopReport();
            grupo.clasesT = clases.ToList();
            grupo.maestrosT = maestros.ToList();
            grupo.inscripcionT = inscripciones.ToList();

            return View(grupo.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GruopReport lo estas declarando como un objeto y no como una lista... un objeto simple no se puede paginar.
No entiendo que quiere hacer la vista, pero es probable que debas paginar las listas que recuperas, pero esto es muy con pinzas porque no se que hace la vista.

por ejemplo así:

```
        var grupo = new GruopReport();
        grupo.clasesT = clases.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
        grupo.maestrosT = maestros.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
        grupo.inscripcionT = inscripciones.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

        return View(grupo);
```